# Returning Matched Attribute Only in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following data structure. The DB contains multiple instances all with the same base-level data structure.

```
{
_id: ObjectId('5f4ceabe521de56d99738fd4'),
position: 11,
entropy: 0.4582005345072268,
supports: 61,
sequences: [
    {
        position: 11,
        sequence: 'CLVFAQKIP',
        count: 56,
        conservation: 91.80327868852459,
        motif_short: 'I',
        motif_long: 'Index',
        id: [
            'ASU55526.1',
            'ASU55528.1',
            'QBM69729.1',
            'QJR40421.1'
        ],
        strain: [
            'Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/164/2016',
            'Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/1185/2016',
            'Influenza A virus A/China/71517/2016',
            'Influenza A virus A/Jiangxi/2017lgfh0026/2016'
        ],
        country: [
            'HA Hemagglutinin',
            'HA Hemagglutinin',
            'HA Hemagglutinin',
            'HA Hemagglutinin'
        ],
        host: [
            'Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/164/2016',
            'Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/1185/2016',
            'Influenza A virus A/China/71517/2016',
            'Influenza A virus A/Jiangxi/2017lgfh0026/2016'
        ]
    },
    {
        position: 11,
        sequence: 'CLVFAQKLP',
        count: 4,
        conservation: 6.557377049180328,
        motif_short: 'Ma',
        motif_long: 'Major',
        id: [
            'APQ31289.1',
            'APQ31290.1',
            'QJR40413.1',
            'QJR40414.1'
        ],
        strain: [
            'Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s200/2016',
            'Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s175/2016',
            'Influenza A virus A/Jiangxi/2016lgfh1021/2016',
            'Influenza A virus A/Jiangxi/2017lgfh0045/2016'
        ],
        country: [
            'HA Hemagglutinin',
            'HA Hemagglutinin',
            'HA Hemagglutinin',
            'HA Hemagglutinin'
        ],
        host: [
            'Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s200/2016',
            'Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s175/2016',
            'Influenza A virus A/Jiangxi/2016lgfh1021/2016',
            'Influenza A virus A/Jiangxi/2017lgfh0045/2016'
        ]
    },
    {
        position: 11,
        sequence: 'CLDFAQKIP',
        count: 1,
        conservation: 1.639344262295082,
        motif_short: 'U',
        motif_long: 'Unique',
        id: [
            'APQ31291.1'
        ],
        strain: [
            'Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s228/2016'
        ],
        country: [
            'HA Hemagglutinin'
        ],
        host: [
            'Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s228/2016'
        ]
    }
],
variants: 3
```

}

What I need is to get the sequence (not the entire row, or the sequences list) where the "motif_short" attribute is equal to "I". At times there could be two or more of these, but in this particular example, there is only one "I" sequence.

I am using Python (PyMongo) and after a bunch of tries I'm left with half a solution and no hair on my head.

```
db.document.find({'sequences.motif_short': {"$eq": 'I'}}, {'sequences': 1, '_id': 0})
```

This obviously gives me the entire "sequences" attribute for the matches, which is not what I'm looking for.

I'm relatively new to Mongo so I'm guessing this is a fairly simple issue. Please help me out.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection-on-embedded-documents-in-an-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with an aggregate ([try it](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZCGqeKcY3VJ))

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$sequences"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "sequences.motif_short": {
        "$eq": "I"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "sequences": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

the `$unwind`, split the list of sequences in multiple documents

With the `$match` you apply you condition : `sequences.motif_short = "I"`

And with the `$project`, you keep only the fields that you want

---

here is an [example](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html) of using aggregates with `pymongo`

Comment: That was beautiful. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: aggregate are really powerful in mongodb. You can do nearly what you want your data